# Is it possible to use cin and getline one after the other on the same line?

Tags: c++, cin, getline

My input is a line such as:

12345 14 14 15 15

Where 12345 is a student's id number that can vary in size, and the rest of the input is the student's scores. From this line, I am trying to store the id into one variable and the scores, which I will then convert into an int array, into another. I tried doing something like this:

```
int id;
std::string scores;
std::cin >> id;
std::cin.ignore(' '); //ignore the space after the id number
std::getline(std::cin, scores); //store the rest of the line into scores
```

This doesn't seem to be working though. Is something like this possible?

I thought I could instead use substring to separate the two portions, but since the length of the id number can vary, I don't think I'd be able to.

What would be the best way to tackle what I'm trying to do? Sorry if this is kind of trivial; I'm still a beginner in C++.

Comment: Can you give us actual code that compiles and runs? (And reproduces your issue)

Comment: In which sense it "doesn't seem to be working"? The thing I'd change is I'd use `std::ws` to skip space rather than using `ignore()`.

Comment: Your use of `ignore` is incorrect. The first parameter to `ignore` is the number of characters to ignore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what isn't working but I certainly wouldn't use `ignore()` to ignore separating space. Instead, I'd just use

```
std::getline(std::cin >> id >> std::ws, scores);
```

The manipulator `std::ws` will ignore all whitespace.

Comment: +1, you just taught me `std::ws`. I just feel saving the line hurts readability; I would split `getline()` to a separate statement.

Comment: @Angew: I agree that different people are used to reading different things. Since I always check my inputs I'd need one expression and the alternatives are what I wrote in the answer or `std::cin >> id >> std::ws && std::getline(std::cin, scores)`. Since I also dislike saying what I said before, I prefer not to repeat `std::cin`.

Answer (score 2):

`std::basic_istream::ignore()` does not do what you think it does. If you consult a [suitable reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore), you'll find that the first parameter is the *number of characters* to ignore, and the second one is the delimiter. You're basically asking it to ignore 32 characters (since 32 is the ASCII code of space).

You want this instead:

```
int id;
std::string scores;
std::cin >> id;
std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), ' '); //ignore all characters until a space is found
std::getline(std::cin, scores); //store the rest of the line into scores
```

Alternatively, if you know there will always be just one space after it, simply call `std::cin.ignore();` without arguments, since that implies ignoring 1 character.

Comment: +1 You can also do `std::getline(std::cin >> id >> std::ws, line)`.

Comment: @0x499602D2 You can post that as an alternative answer. I would upvote you, I actually learned something I didn't know (`std::ws`).